# Access these dictionary values in flask template

Tags: python, mysql, templates, flask

My Template is outputting the below. It doesnt pull in any of the queried values, but the `page loads fine` and `doesnt fail`, but it doesnt show any of the `values`.

I double checked the `query` in a `mysqlmonitor`, and it pulls 3 records as it should.

```
 <li><a href="http://blog.mysite.com/wordpress///"></a></li>
```

**In the `templates/index.html` I have:**

```
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
        <li><a href="http://blog.mysite.com/wordpress/{{blogpost[2]}}/{{blogpost[3]}}/{{blogpost[1]}}">{{blogpost[0]}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li>no blog posts right now...</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

`app.py` has this:

```
import pymysql.cursors
app = Flask(__name__)
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='myuser', port=3306, password='mypass', db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
    form = EmailForm()

    curs = connection.cursor()

    curs.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name, YEAR(post_date) as YEAR, MONTH(post_date) as MONTH FROM mydb.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")


    blogposts = curs.fetchall()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, blogposts=blogposts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**UPDATE** I think my `for()` is not working correctly, because when i update in the `template` i get all the data like:

```
 [{u'MONTH': 12, u'YEAR': 2016, u'post_name': u'data is here', u'post_title': u'data is here'}, 
{u'MONTH': 12, u'YEAR': 2016, u'post_name': u'data is here', u'post_title': u"data is here"}]
```

How can i access this data in my **flask** `template` ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try finding out what is being sent to the template. Add `print(blogposts)` to the email function - just below the `if request.method == 'POST':` line and see what information it gives you.

If blogposts is a list of dictionaries, then you cannot access them by number. You need to use the name of the key. For example, you will need to change `blogpost[0]` to `blogpost['name']`. With Flask's templates you can also use the dot notation, so the blogpost name would become `blogpost.name`.

Answer (score 3):

```
   @app.route('/get', methods=['POST','GET'])
   def requestCustomerDataFromTestForm():
       data={'id':1, 'name':'Josh'}
       return render_template("index.html", data = data)
```

In index.html

```
{% if data %}
<h1>{{data['id']}}</h1>
<h1>{{data['name']}}</h1>
{% endif%}
```

Or.. you can also iterate

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for key, value in data.items() %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Or, to display all data with their index

```
{% if data %}

<p>{{data}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: value = "{{ data['full_name']}}"  not working  to me. But  value = "{{ data}}" print all  data in jinja2 template